# How to sort by dates from a dictionary I created?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I created a dictionary in a separate file called cars.txt. The purpose of my code is to return whats in the dictionary and sort them. My problem is that now my code just returns the make/model, not the year let alone the years being sorted. Thank for the help.

```
class Car:
    def __init__(make,model,year):
        self.make=make
        self.year=year

        def set_year(year):
            self.year=year

        def get_year(self):
            return self.year

        def display(self):
            return (self.make, ":" , self.year)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.make + " : " + str(self.model)

        def __lt__(self,other):
            return self.year<other.title

        def __repr__(self):
            return str(self)

def constructDictionary():
    dict = {}
    file = open("cars.txt","r");
    for line in file:
        data = line.split(" ")
        dict[data[0].strip()]=data[1].strip()
    file.close()
    return dict;

def main():
    dict=constructDictionary()
    [value for (key, value) in sorted(dict.items())]
    aList=dict
    print(aList)
main()
```

Comment: `[value for (key, value) in sorted(dict.items())]` isn't being 'saved'. you need to assign it to a variable, or are you trying to sort a dictionary, because dictionaries are orderable.

Comment: Also, where is the date ? is it in the keys or the values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line is not doing anything in your code:

```
[value for (key, value) in sorted(dict.items())]
```

This is a list comprehension, used to build lists, and returns a list. If you change your `main` to

```
def main():
    dict=constructDictionary()
    alist = [value for (key, value) in sorted(dict.items())]
    print(aList)
```

Then your code will print a list containing the values of the dictionary, **sorted by key**. It will be sorted by the dictionary keys, since you used `dict.items()` and when sorting tuples, `sorted` will first compare the first element of the tuples, then the second, etc.

If you want to sort by the values in the dictionary, just change the list comprehension to

```
alist = list(sorted(dict.values()))
```

---

One tip: Python isn't Java. It's not recommended to use getters and setters. Look into `property` for that or just directly access the variables, if you are not interested in controlling an invariant or anything like that.

Also, instead of manually closing the file, you can use a `context manager`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to save `[value for (key, value) in sorted(dict.items())]` somewhere. Second, if you wanna sort by values, just get the values with dict.values() and sort them.

If you need any more processing in the values before sorting, you can use `sorted(values, key=somefunction)`, where somefunction will be a function that process the value so it can be properly sorted, converting it to integers, for instance, if the values are years and you wanna sort them numerically.